# What is needed to distribute an iOS app through SOTI Mobicontrol

Tags: ios, enterprise, soti

I am about to sign an agreement to distribute a good amount of copies of my app to a company. They are using SOTI Mobicontrol for distribution.

Could anyone please explain what is needed from our end to make this smooth? First time I am doing this. I do have an LLC on my developer account. Do I need to upgrade to enterprise membership?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a specific version available to that company as a [B2B app](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/). You can set a different price on the B2B app (free if they are paying your directly). The purchaser needs to nominate an AppleID that you will list against the B2B app in iTunesConnect. This AppleID can then “purchase” the app in the Enterprise volume purchase store and distribute it via their MDM.

The other option the client can just purchase “x”copies of your existing app through the volume purchase store. In this case payment would go through the App Store with Apple taking their cut.

Comment: Paul, thanks! I have a follow up. When you say "specific version". Does that mean that I can have different builds for each customer under the same bundle? Or would I need to make a new app for each customer? Thanks!

Comment: You can make a B2B version available for more than one customer (you can register more than one authorised AppleID against the app in iTunesConnect) or you can make a customer specific build, say, with customer specific branding. Each app in iTunesConnect must have a unique bundle Id, so if you wanted specific versions for specific customers, each would have its own bundle Id, but they could share common source code.

Comment: I understand. I was under the impression that I could give them an IPA file and they could do their own in house distribution. I guess that is not the case.

Comment: No, they can do that if they have an enterprise program and the ipa is signed by that membership, but for you to provide an app as a third party, B2 or VPP is the way to go.